# The api.soundcloud.com never respond on HTTP

Tags: soundcloud

When ping `api.soundcloud.com`, no problem:

```
ping api.soundcloud.com
PING d3ad8414wy4gwn.cloudfront.net (52.85.73.227) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

64 bytes from server-52-85-73-227.lhr3.r.cloudfront.net (52.85.73.227): icmp_seq=1 ttl=247 time=4.06 ms

But when to communicate on HTTP:

```
curl http://api.soundcloud.com/
```

I got (after a long time) this response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: 4fFcKB1pjCSFOLlNJcBpG36rPSRPqb1eHUSzUkPbDqyZD2HWSdKBfw==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I never got response. The problem is only on my server (work from another IP), behind `178.32.223.76` public IP address.

My server is black listed ? How to know that ? What can i do ?

Comment: What that curl stands for? Try to curl -s -D- http://api.soundcloud.com/ you will see an Unauthorized status code.

Comment: @GoingSolo The command is for expose the problem (in my real code, i retrieve track infos). When use `-s -D-` additional parameters: Same cloudfront HTML response.